# Google App Engine Datastore Admin is disabled due to application hidden by an alias

Tags: google-app-engine, data-migration, datastore-admin

Recently I migrated my application to the High-Replication datastore using the migration tool.

- The Datastore Admin page now isnt diplaying correctly:

  Error: Server Error

  The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
  If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this
  error message and the query that caused it.

When I visit the Datastore Admin in the old application (the one I migrated from) I get the following notifications:

- This application is hidden by an alias. The application lrweb2012 has
  an alias that causes it to receive all traffic normally directed at
  this one. Unless you are looking for historical data, you probably
  want to see that application.
- Datastore Admin is disabled. Because lrweb2012 has an alias that
  shadows this application the Datastore Admin tool cannot be used.

Can anyone experianced suggest what is going on, and how I may go about resolving this issue?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

You migrated your app, so you probably want to be looking at the admin for lrweb2012-hrd (or wherever you migrated it to) instead of the old setup. 
Use the drop-down at the top-left corner to pick a different app.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for answering. Yes I went ahead and looked their initially, but this is the page where I receive the error: Server Error

The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. If the problem persists, please report your problem and mention this error message and the query that caused it.

the old app displays the other too notification errors posted above.

Is there a way outside of the Google apps admin page to download this perhaps?